# How to convert MKV to MP4 using ffmpeg keeping all video, audio tracks and subtitles?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, convert, mp4, mkv

I have been trying to convert mkv to mp4 using
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy  output.mp4`

The `input.mkv` has two different `audio track` and one `subtitle` .

But the problem I am getting is that when I convert only the default `audio track` remains and the 2nd `audio track` & the `subtitle` does not get converted

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGmNr.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-map` advanced option. See manpages (`man ffmpeg`) but basically use `-map 0`

Excerpt from manpage:

```
For example, to map ALL streams from the first input file to output 

ffmpeg -i INPUT -map 0 output
```

Comment: It works!!! I also just figured it out right now . I used `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v copy -map 0  -c:s mov_text -x265-params crf=25  output.mp4` . ` -c:s mov_text -x265-params crf=25` for subtitles . `-map 0` for audio tracks. `-c:v copy ` for video stream

Comment: @ShravanMhatre You are [stream copying](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the video with `-c:v copy`, so `-x265-params crf=25` is being ignored.

Comment: @Ilogan - you are correct. I've updated my answer - and removed my unqualified comment ;-)

Comment: @llogan I am stream copying because I just wanted to change the video extension not the codec.

Answer (score 6):

You may not use a mp4 container if the subtitle stream contains a format other than the special `MPEG-4 Timed Text`format. But you can tranform it:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec mov_text output.mp4`

This way you take all streams including the converted subtitles.

This command only copies the video and audio streams, they are not reencoded. The subtitles are translated into "timed text"

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I have many .mp4 files with multiple audio streams & multiple subtitle streams. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14

Comment: yes-I'Ve seen that. But for me it doesn't work using ffmpeg:
` Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument ` . If i change to "output.mkv" it works. It works with "timedText" for mp4 but not with "subrip" - which is on most DVD and bluerays. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

As a GUI for ffmpeg there is this tool: [dmMediaConverter](https://sites.google.com/site/dmsimpleapps/dmMediaConverter?authuser=0).

Very easy to use, but with subtitles I had to edit the subtitle codec and change to mov_text, as indicated in the other answer by @kanehekili.

[image]